# How to Factorise $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2xy - 2yz - 2zx$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quaternions

How do you factorise

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2xy - 2yz - 2zx$ ?

If those minus sings were pluses it would be a lot simpler. I wondered if there was some kind of use of imaginary units which would yield those minus signs.

The factorisation could be done by introducing 3 units, $i, j, k$ such that,

$$
i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = 1 \\
ij = jk = ki = -1
$$

which sort of look like quaternions, but not quite. In this case the factorisation becomes,
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2xy - 2yz - 2zx = (ix + jy + kz)^2.
$$

I didn't know if there was some algebra which obeyed these properties.

Comment: Honestly, can't think of a nice factorization of this. The best I can think of is $$(x-y-z)^2-4yz$$But maybe there is a way to factor this.

Comment: Yea, I don't know if it exists. I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: It doesn't exist, at least how you've formulated it. To see why, observe that $i^2=j^2=k^2=1$ implies that all $3$ commute with all other numbers, which contradicts the second line.

Comment: Is there some other algebra which works?

Comment: In your system, $i=-j$ because $ijj=-1j\iff i=-j$. However, maybe there is a stricter rule-set to develop this?

Comment: Assuming your algebra is associative and that $1$ is identity, we end up getting $i = -j$ and other symmetric results. But then this means that $$i = -j = k = -i$$ and so $i = -i$. But this would mean that $i = j = k = 0$, which would mess it up.

Comment: What if you drop the requirement that it is associative (but keep commutative) @AryamanMaithani

Comment: I don't think I'm using commutativity anywhere. (Apart from $\pm 1$ commuting with everything.)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I think commutativity is needed to satisfy the expansion. I'm not sure if associativity is

Comment: Oh, I just realised I misunderstood your earlier comment. Sadly, I don't have knowledge of non-associative algebras.

Comment: If you drop the requirement of commutativity, then the second line of identities becomes $ij + ji = -2$ etc, and you're done. This gives an eight dimensional associative algebra over your base field, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

As a general principle, you should expect that an inhomogeneous polynomial in $\ge2$ variables, or a homogeneous polynomial in $\ge3$ variables will be irreducible, i.e. hove no further factorization.

An almost-always-valid technique in a case like yours is to set one of the homogeneous variables to $1$ and look at the new inhomogeneous equation. Setting $z=1$, you get
$$x^2+y^2+1-2xy-2x-2y=0\,,$$
which is a nice parabola, axis along the diagonal. If your polynomial had been factorable, the graph would have been two lines.

So my recommendation to you is that you stop and admire the polynomial as it stands. It’s not at all clear to me what any proposed factorization would mean, if the variables were going to be allowed to be in a noncommutative ring: $xy$ would not be $yx$, for instance, and you would have to throw out tools like the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about whether the polynomial is factorizable over some other rings, e.g. the quaternions. It is obviously factorizable over rings where $4 = 0$, but that's probably not the intended case ...

Comment: @WhatsUp What do you mean by 4=0. I haven’t seen that before.

Comment: @BenjaminRogers-Newsome He is talking about "rings", which are algebraic structures to generalize fields. Rings have two binary operators, namely $+$ and $*$ and satisfy some conditions. For example, The Set of Real Numbers ($\Bbb R$) is a ring, more precisely it's a Commutative Ring. Some rings can also contain absurd results like $4=0$

Answer (score 0):

Solving the equation

$f(x,y,z)=x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} - 2xy - 2yz - 2zx=0$,

compared to $z$ for example, we factorise:

$x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} - 2xy - 2yz - 2zx=$

$(x+y-z+2\sqrt{xy})(x+y-z-2\sqrt{xy})$.